# When a user doesn't completed the sign-up steps, I'd like to re-direct them to their Account Page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that has a 3 step sign-up process and on the first page/steps they're required to enter an email and password, the second page/steps they're required to fill out their address and organization details and on the third page/steps their required to enter their CC information.

Now in some cases, a user may fill in the first page steps and then close the browser on the second page. If this happens they should still be able to login with their email + password, however they should only be limited to viewing the Account Page until they fill in the rest of the required details.

How might I accomplish this?

Happy to provide any necessary code upon request!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a status flag in a user table and update it based on whether user's profile completion. After login, you can check the value of this attribute for the logged in user, perform required actions like redirect to account page and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On First page, Create a Next button-with a message that doing so, User account will be created.

On Click of Next,create his/her account.

Have a before filter in application_controller.rb

def account_complete

if user_second_attributes.nil?

```
 redirect_to second_page
```

elsif user_third_attributes.nil?

```
 redirect_to third_page
```

else

```
redirect_to admin page
```

end
end

If else condition are to check if any data is present in database or not.

If second sheet attributes are not present,it will redirect to second page
If third sheet attributes are not present,it will redirect to third page 
If all data exists , it will go to home page

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would separate the user login information from the address information, so that you can separate your required field.

If a user clicks on "next" (second page), your site has to create a new user (for example with an has_one :address_field, validates_presence_of :address_field, :on => :update) without an address.

When your user logs-in you can check, if address != null and redirect to the second page view.